# Windows XP "The setup files are corrupted. Please obtain a new copy of the program"

Tags: windows-xp, installation, virtualbox, windows-installer

I just installed a copy of XP I had lying around into a VM using virtualbox. I then loaded a game disc (syberia -- awesome game) and proceeded with the install.

However, when I click the .exe, Windows gives me the following error:

```
The setup files are corrupted. Please obtain a new copy of the program.
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

I've had this issue once before and I solved it by performing a full system update and getting the newest version of Windows Installer. In your case, I would recommend you try either a newer or older version of WI.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your temp folders ([CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) can help), uninstall syberia and reboot. Try re-installing once again, ensuring any security software is disabled during the install.

If the game requires OpenGL/DirectX (likely), you will have to install the Guest Additions first. Even then, these drivers are still experimental.

Comment: It never got installed though. This is when I click on the actual installer. Plus this is a 100% clean windows install.

Comment: Try the game disc on your host system -- does it produce the same error?

Comment: My host is a linux build (opensuse) but Wine can open the installer perfectly.

Comment: Odd, perhaps the CD emulation driver isn't passing the data correctly to the virtual machine. Try copying the CD install files to your Linux host then from there transfer them with a vbox share.

Comment: Just finished trying that. Same error occurs, very weird. I thought it might be an issue with Windows Installer but I'm not sure how to diagnose that.

Comment: It's a fresh install... hmm. Have you fully updated Windows? There are numerous windows installer packages that are updated. Might be easier to get the game going under WINE :D

Comment: @MaxMackie let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/944/discussion-between-john-t-and-maxmackie)

Comment: Did you, perchance, install XP64 bit?  If the game installer setup app is 16 bit, I have heard from some people that XP64 throws all kinds of fits and often won't launch them at all.  I've never installed XP64 and tried it myself though.